# Quicksort 3-way partitioning in java libraries

Tags: java, quicksort

Is an implementation of 3-way partitioning quicksort available in the Java platform or do I have to implement it by myself?

I could find nothing in the documentation, only implementations from algorithms books and tutorials. Given a prior knowledge of the sequence this variant can lead to better performances, why isn't a ready-to-use implementation already available in the standard packages?

Comment: Seems like a real question to me - why all the close votes? If it's a duplicate - flag as such. If it's poorly researched, downvote.

Comment: Well, maybe the question was a little too straightforward...

Comment: "*is there a good reason not to make a ready-to-use implementation available in the standard packages*" > I would strip this part out because it makes your question subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to have been an implementation in [OpenJDK 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java)